# docker swarm 1.12 --name option not recognized

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to create the following service in Docker Swarm Mode (1.12 rc5)

```
docker service create --replicas 1 –-name mongo -p 27017:27017/tcp –-network ugidotnet15 mongo:3.2
```

it's seems to me ok, but i receive the following error message

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = ContainerSpec: "–-name" is not a valid repository/tag
```

i really don't understand what's wrong here

Comment: Thanks, it didn't worked.
after some tries I was successful: syntax is ok, but I had to rewrite piece by piece the entire command before it worked.
I really don't know why

Comment: It seems that the first dash in `--name` in the code you pasted is wrong (it's other character): `In [1]: "docker service create --replicas 1 –-name mongo -p 27017:27017/tcp –-network ugidotnet15 mongo:3.2".encode('utf-8')
Out[1]: b'docker service create --replicas 1 \xe2\x80\x93-name mongo -p 27017:27017/tcp \xe2\x80\x93-network ugidotnet15 mongo:3.2'
`